# How to return values from Haneke's async fetch method

Tags: swift, asynchronous, closures, completionhandler, haneke

I'm trying to parse some data that I cached using **Haneke Swift**. I've cached the data and have written the parser to accomplish this. This parser is in a separate class called `AssembleCalendar()`.

Using Haneke's [example code](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) for fetching, I've tried with complete and utter failure to actually return a value from the closure.

**My attempt**

```
func getScheduledItems() -> [ScheduledItem] {
    
    var scheduledItem = [ScheduledItem]() // initialize array

    let cache = Shared.dataCache
    cache.fetch(key: "CalendarData").onSuccess { data in
        
        scheduledItem = AssembleCalendar().assimilate(data) // update array
        print(scheduledItem) // array returns expected value
        
    }

    print(scheduledItem) // array returns nil
    return scheduledItem // returns nil
}
```

**What I know**

I understand that this is an asynchronous issue. My code isn't waiting for my `AssembleCalendar()` parser to finish. It's just running each line and returns nil long before my scheduledItem receives a value. I've tried *many, many solutions* and read quite a few examples online but I cannot figure out how to retrieve a value from this closure in this scenario.

## My question

How can I get .fetch() to return a value before my function hits nil?

---

**update:**

Here's my code in context:

```
class Schedule {

    var items : [ScheduledItem]
    
    init() {
        items = getScheduledItems() // Schedule.getScheduledItems()
    }
    
    func getScheduledItems(completion: (items: [ScheduledItem]) -> ()) {
        
        var scheduledItem = [ScheduledItem]() // initialize array
        
        let cache = Shared.dataCache
        cache.fetch(key: "CalendarData").onSuccess { data in
            
            scheduledItem = AssembleCalendar().assimilate(data) // update array
            print(scheduledItem) // array returns expected value
            completion(items: scheduledItem)
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're passing an array of ScheduledItem into the init function, why are you not setting that to the classes items variable instead of calling a function to get them? Or if you do need to use that function, do it before calling the init function of Schedule

Comment: ignore that line, it was part of a temporary work-around so I could continue developing, I'll remove that line

Comment: I understand that you're trying to use a factory method here but in this case I don't believe it is the right approach. If you need to get your data in an asynch way then I would call that before instantiating the class. I will amend my answer to show you.

Comment: Thanks Swinny, I'm looking at some of your other useful answers on this topic.

Comment: No problem, I have updated my answer to show a possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch() is using a completion handler, this means that the block of code called in there is actually executing AFTER your return statement has been executed. This is why it is returning nil. To get around this, you can use your own completion handler to return the information:

```
class Schedule {

    var items = [ScheduledItem]()

    init(items: [ScheduledItem]) {
        self.items = items
    }

    class func getScheduledItems(completion: (items: [ScheduledItem]) -> ()) {

        var scheduledItem = [ScheduledItem]() // initialize array

        let cache = Shared.dataCache
        cache.fetch(key: "CalendarData").onSuccess { data in

            scheduledItem = AssembleCalendar().assimilate(data) // update array
            print(scheduledItem) // array returns expected value
            completion(items: scheduledItem)

        }
    }
}
```

Then initialise the class using this:

```
Schedule.getScheduledItems { (items) -> () in
    var schedule = Schedule(items: items)
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a couple of errors with this in Xcode 7. 1.) Expected parameter type following ':' 2.) Expected '{' in body of function declaration.

Comment: What line are you getting it on?

Comment: I have also updated my answer with how to implement this.

Comment: updated my main post, I am trying to initialize a value with this function

Comment: Please note, I have just updated my answer to make `items` an empty array by default so that this will compile

Comment: You're awesome, you know that right? Thanks, I've still got a lot to learn

Comment: Thank you :) We all still have a lot to learn, nature of the beast! Good luck

Comment: Swinny, one more question. How would I get a value out of Schedule.getScheduledItems { (items) -> () in
    var schedule = Schedule(items: items)
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89332/discussion-between-swinny89-and-dan-beaulieu).

Comment: I tried this var schedule = Schedule.getScheduledItems { (items) -> () in
    var schedule = Schedule(items: items)
}